# Inject @Value in spring @component class

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with inject properties in my `@Component` class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("my.package.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:setting.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
  return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

Component class

```
@Component
public class Why {
@Value("${sc.ws.user}")
private  String user;

public  void  testProperties(){
    System.out.println(user);
  }
}
```

Initial class for testing

```
Why w = new Why();
w.testProperties();
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `Why w = new Why();` gives you an instance not managed by spring.. so no `@Value` for `w`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997092/autowiring-in-spring-bean-component-created-with-new-keyword

Comment: `@Autowired` and `@Value` are more or less the same. If your object isn't a Spring bean, Spring won't have processed it.